# Storing User Doctrine object in symfony 1.4

Tags: session, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Throughout the application I need to access User object (Doctrine) several times per execution (I mean each time page is displayed) so on some, and instead of retrieving it from database every time, I thought it would be better to store it once and then reuse it.

Can I store it in sfContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony discourages saving objects into the session, see here for example: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_accessing_the_user_session

... But you can save user_ids and other bits that save on queries. It really depends on whether the things you need to do on all those pages require the entire user object. If yes, `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()` is what you'll end up using everywhere.

Comment: I'm not talking about saving user object in session, I mean I need to have the user object over the period of request, during execution. For example, one of the components loads user every time it's requested from database. In actions I do not want to get user again if it was loaded in the component so I need to make component variable available to action. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you certain it gets loaded each time? It should just create one actual query to the database, even when it's inside componenets.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the *currently logged in user* object, it should already automatically be loaded for you.  At the point of authentication, the system loads the user record and it will remain there in the session.

In actions, you can retrieve the user object with:

```
$this->getUser()
```

In a view, it's already loaded into the variable:

```
$sf_user
```